# Does awk support en eval like construct to run a command by concatenating arguments

Tags: awk, gawk

This came up in one my recent answers to achieve an use-case of doing a simple arithmetic evaluation using `awk` alone. Imagine a simple trivial function for this

```
awkf () { awk -v argv="$*" 'BEGIN{ pi=3.14159265359; printf "%5.5f\n", argv }' ; }
```

apparently I intended to use it do arithmetic like

```
awkf "1+2"
```

but these don't produce the output as expected. I ended up using `$*` inside double-quotes of the body of the `awk` to implement this. Though it could work, I don't want to do that. Is there a way to do this to achieve a result as

```
awkf () { awk -v argv="$*" 'BEGIN{ pi=3.14159265359; printf "%5.5f\n", 1+2}' ; }
#                                                                      ^^^^ when I pass "1+2"
```

i.e doing `awkf "1+2"` I'd expect to get result as `3.00000`

Suggesting other tools like `bc` is beyond the scope of this current question. Just wanted to know, how to use `awk` for this.

Comment: Could you describe this `printf "%5.5f\n", 1+2` further? Is it missing any `()` perhaps?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8353396

Comment: @DaemonPainter : That would sum the values given and print the result as provided in the format specifier

Comment: I tried `awkf () { awk -v argv="$*" 'BEGIN{ pi=3.14159265359; printf "%5.5f\n", 1+2}' ; }` with no output. Right after, a `awkf --help` it printed `3.0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write your script as a function

```
$ function awkf() { awk "BEGIN{print $*}"; }
$ awkf 4/3
1.33333

$ awkf 3 + 4
7
```

to add formatting, you have to do quote dance...

```
$ function awkf() { awk "BEGIN{printf "\"%5.5f\\n\"," $*}"; }
```

Comment: I'd like this one, one problem being it leaves out the `printf` format specifier options. Is it possible with `printf`?